# Отсутствует окно Samples в unity Animation, не понимаю как его включить

Tags: unity3d

Отсутствует окно Samples в unity Animation вследствие чего невозможно изменить количество кадров. Хотелось бы узнать куда оно пропало и как его включить

[image: Как должно быть]

[image: Как есть]

Comment: Сверху как должно быть, снизу как есть

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В новой версии Unity эта настройка неплохо так "спряталась".

В окне "**Animation**" нажмите на кнопку настроек (*шестеренка с треугольником*) и выберите нужное значение через "**Set Sample Rate**".

Так же можно вернуть привычное отображение - в том же меню выберите "**Show Sample Rate**".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]